# Is it possible to store UTF8-mb4 in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have a chat server that stores messages in MongoDB...emoticons (emoji specifically) are giving me grief.

Apparently emoticons/emoji are UTF8-mb4 encoded...can MongoDB store data in this encoding? If it can't stored UTF8-mb4 directly is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB supports UTF8 which supports all characters (variable byte length).

The original implementation "utf8" by MySQL was only for up to 3 Bytes (like many other implementations). The MySQL implementation called 'utf8-mb4' is actually up to 4 Bytes long (like the official RFC recommends it).

So utf8-mb4 in MySQL is the same as UTF8 in mongoDB.

What I saw in my Tests:
Robomongo does not support chinese 4 Byte characters while for example MongoVUE has no problems.

Interesting article about the utf8 max byte size: https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char/

(Answer updated)

Comment: I think the characters are being encoded as standard UTF-8 when they're written to the database :s